# Capturing Accept/Decline/Propose New Time event in Outlook Add-in C# for Meeting Request

Tags: c#, xml, outlook, add-in, ribbon

I have been working on an Outlook Add-In and I need to be able to capture the click event of three buttons (Accept, Reject and Propose New Time) which are displayed when a user receives a meeting request.

I have looked around online and I think that these can be handled in .xml but for some reason, I can't seem to get my event to fire.

It seems like the following link provides something of an answer to my question and this is currently the strategy I am following.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c64ea6e5-5f95-402d-b711-6812dac7d593/any-meeting-event-handler-in-outlook-2010-using-cnet-?forum=outlookdev

I have added an .xml Ribbon Item to the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>
    <command idMso="DeclineInvitationNoResponse" onAction="Decline"/>
    <command idMso="AcceptInvitationNoResponse" onAction="Accept"/>
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

In the .cs file for the Ribbon I have:

```
 namespace EquipmentScheduler
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class AlterMeetingResponse : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

        public AlterMeetingResponse()
        {
        }

        #region IRibbonExtensibility Members

        public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
            return GetResourceText("EquipmentScheduler.AlterMeetingResponse.xml");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Ribbon Callbacks
        //Create callback methods here. For more information about adding callback methods, select the Ribbon XML item in Solution Explorer and then press F1

        public void Decline(Office.IRibbonControl Control, bool Cancel)
        {
            Debug.Print("Decline button hit");
        }
        public void Accept(Office.IRibbonControl Control, bool Cancel)
        {
            Debug.Print("Accept button hit");

            }
        }
        public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
        {
            this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Helpers

        private static string GetResourceText(string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resourceNames = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (string.Compare(resourceName, resourceNames[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNames[i])))
                    {
                        if (resourceReader != null)
                        {
                            return resourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I have also added the following function to ThisAddIn.cs

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new AlterMeetingResponse();
        }
```

However, I have not managed to get the code in the Accept/Reject routines to run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Benjamin Biggs

Comment: If you want us to find the problem at your code, you should post your code. Otherwise we can't help you to get it working.

Comment: Apologies. I have added some code blocks. If you need me to explain anything else, then I can. I don't really understand the url (?) as part of the .xml file. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and coding an add-in for Outlook 2007.

Comment: Okay that's not my field of activity, but thanks for providing code. I hope some other experts can help you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?